# SQL query fetch the complete list of data from table, rather between the date range

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a question here, the attached screen shot[image: The sql]

```
SELECT 
    intvw.Tran_no RequestNo, stkdl.std_tran_no RamcoTranNo, 
    stkhd.sth_tran_date TranDate,
    intvw.Bg_Code ItemCode, intvw.reqdqty ReqQty, 
    stkdl.std_tran_quantity TransferQty, 
    stkdl.std_from_lot_no, (intvw.reqdqty-stkdl.std_tran_quantity) * -1 Varience,
    intvw.From_Wh_Code FromWH, intvw.To_Wh_Code ToWH
FROM  
    res_his_interface_stock_vw intvw 
LEFT JOIN 
    skm_stocktransfer_dtl stkdl ON intvw.Tran_no = stkdl.std_tran_no
                                AND intvw.Bg_Code = stkdl.std_item_code 
                                AND intvw.From_Wh_Code = stkdl.std_from_wh_code
LEFT JOIN 
    skm_stocktransfer_hdr stkhd ON stkhd.sth_tran_no = stkdl.std_tran_no 
                                AND stkhd.sth_tran_date BETWEEN '2020-01-19 00:00:00.000' AND '2020-01-19 00:00:00.000' -- datatype: datetime
                                AND stkhd.sth_status = 'AU'  -- checks transaction authorised or not
WHERE 
    intvw.From_Wh_Code = 'MAINSTRS'
    --AND stkhd.sth_tran_date BETWEEN '2020-01-19 00:00:00.000'  AND '2020-01-19 00:00:00.000' -- removes the null rows.
    AND intvw.Tran_no = 'R0000085590'  -- if commented all rows instead of date range.
ORDER BY 
    1 DESC
```

When I keep the date range and tran_no, the below results appear, the moment comments on tran_no and try to see the result for the given date range, instead of it, it gives all data from day one till date.

I don't get know what's wrong here, please help.

Comment: I don't follow what your problem is here. You also know ask a question here, so it's impossible for us to give an answer. Sample data, which we can use to replicate the undesired behaviour and expected results will help us help you.

Comment: Let me elaborate it more with trans number# R0000085590 as viewpoint. stk req will be initiated, it will be visible in res_his_interface_stock_vw - in this case, 28 item rows reqstd, the skm_stocktransfer_dtl will have same req no as transfer number - in the case 24 rows got trnsfred and 4 rows didnt given to reqstr.. the hdr table consist of transaction date and status.. the qry above with request number generate precise data - it shows 28 rows along with 24 rows tranfrd and 4 items left over.. but when i run it with date range.. instead of that date range it gives whole list from day 1